# Update Long Quarter to Short Quarter using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wish to replace the blank space w a '.' and then shorten the length of the numerical values (ex 2022) by removing the first 2 characters.

**Data**

df =

```
ID  Date        
AA  Q1 2022     
BB  Q4 2024     
CC  Q2 2025     
CC  Q3 2025     
CC  Q1 2021     
DD  Q2 2021
```

**Desired**

```
ID  Date
AA  Q1.22
BB  Q4.24
CC  Q2.25
CC  Q3.25
CC  Q1.21
DD  Q2.21
```

**Doing**

**1.replace blank with '.'**

```
df.Date.fillna(value=., inplace=True)
```

**2.Remove first 2 digits from year**

```
df["Date"].str[2:]
```

**3. possibly concat?**

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) with a regex pattern (`regex=True`):

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].replace(r'\s\d{2}','.',regex=True)

print(df)

   ID   Date
0  AA  Q1.22
1  BB  Q4.24
2  CC  Q2.25
3  CC  Q3.25
4  CC  Q1.21
5  DD  Q2.21
```

Explanation regex pattern `\s\d{2}`:

- `\s` matches any whitespace character
- `\d` matches a digit
- `{2}` matches the previous token (i.e. the digit) exactly 2 times